# How do I get CMake to work with the go programming language?

Tags: cmake, go

I have been using CMake with C++ to build libraries and executables and would like to use the same for the **go programming language**.

**What steps do I need to take to configure CMake so it would work with the go programming language?**

Essentially, my compiler is 6g which produces a compiled foo.6 - I send it to a linker via 6l foo.6 and I am done.  I have the compiler and linker already built and installed.

Obviously, I can just write a simple Makefile for this, but it would be nice to use CMake consistently throughout my project.

TIA for any advice that would help me get started.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might wish to implement CMake' support for Go. Roughly speaking it involves following steps:

1. Create **CMakeDetermineGoCompiler.cmake** module, which would find Go
   compiler for the current system.
2. Create **CMakeGoCompiler.cmake.in** - a
   template, which would be configured by CMakeDetermineGoCompiler.
3. Create **CMakeTestGoCompiler.cmake**, module which would compile a
   simple go source to check if the compiler works.
4. Create **CMakeGoInformation.cmake**, which would set some language-related
   variables (CMAKE_GO_LINK_EXECUTABLE and so on)

These things should be placed in CMAKE_MODULES_DIR. For reference you can take a look at how Java/CXX support is implemented.

Alternatively, if don't want to mess with such internal stuff, you can solve your task by creating a macro(), which would create a bunch of custom targets/commands (see add_custom_{target,command}() documentation).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this simple info for two weeks and it was frustrating because in Modules folder of cmake there are so many files and it gets confusing if you just want to start small. Anyway thanks! Awesome answer!

Comment: Wow! I wish I had found this answer a year ago when I first started trying to do this. Well written answer :)

Comment: Any hope to get an example of the files you mentioned?

Comment: by `CMAKE_MODULES_DIR` you mean `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

It's in your best interest to not use CMake (or any other build system).

Go has a simple, built-in way to build packages: `go build` (which also makes `go get` and `go install` work). `go build`, by design, doesn't require additional tools like make or cmake.

If you use CMake (or any other build system) you'll just make life harder for yourself (if you plan to use libraries developed by others) or for other people (if you plan to develop libraries that are meant to be used by others).

Comment: I think the exception to this is when using `gccgo` and combining object files with existing C, Fortran, Ada or C++ projects, that already uses CMake.

Comment: Or building intermediate files like protobuffers, or building distributable tarballs for release, or basically a bajillion other tasks that people seem to forget exist for people actually writing go projects that are more complicated than `go get` can handle.

Comment: how can I use `go build` to produce `.dll` lib for windows?

Comment: Hey! I need to compile many (~1000) proto-files with cross-dependencies into grpc.pb.go to use them in my proje. How can I do it using native golang build system?

Answer (score 3):

2024 answer.
Given that if you only need to build a stand alone go project, the answer of [Krzysztof Kowalczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983898/4398237) applies, a solution to add a go project into a bigger cmake project, let's say some C/C++ project, is to exploit the ExternalProject module.
Assuming the following directories structure:

```
root_project_dir
    |
    |-> CMakeLists.txt
    |-> go_project_dir
           |
           |-> CMakeLists.txt
           |-> src
```

Something like this in your go project `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(goprj
                    INSTALL_DIR ${HOST_INSTALL_DIR}/bin
                    LOG_CONFIGURE YES
                    LOG_BUILD YES
                    LOG_INSTALL YES
                    LOG_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE YES
                    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
                    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
                    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
                        XDG_CACHE_HOME=/tmp/.cache
                        GOPATH=<SOURCE_DIR>/deps
                        GOROOT=/usr/local/go
                        CGO_ENABLED=0
                        go build -ldflags "-s"
                    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
                    INSTALL_COMMAND cp go_binary_program <INSTALL_DIR>
)

install(PROGRAMS ${HOST_INSTALL_DIR}/bin/go_binary_program DESTINATION ${TARGET_PREFIX}/bin)

configure_file(src/config.json.in src/config.json)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/config.json DESTINATION ${TARGET_PREFIX}/etc)
```

`HOST_INSTALL_DIR`: a variable defined in a parent CMakeFiles.txt, initialised with some path under the cmake build/

`TARGET_PREFIX`: a variable defined in a parent CMakeFiles.txt initialised with some path under the target installation prefix (those specified with `make DESTDIR=/target/install/path install`)

It is important to set **XDG_CACHE_HOME**, **GOPATH**, **CGO_ENABLED** and **GOROOT** if not defined elsewhere as environment variables.

config.json.in in this case contains some variables in the form @SOME_VAR@, that are set by the cmake, using homonymous variables defined in some parent cmake files. This way you can configure your go program with cmake variables.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple go.cmake module for combining C/C++ and Go using CMake.

https://github.com/krumberg/cmake_go