# Is there any way to sign the windows executables generated by the Go compiler?

Tags: go, authenticode

I am trying to find out if there is a possibility to sign executables produced by the Go compiler. I cannot see this in the build/compile options. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Signing an executable is not the responsibility of the compiler, but it is part of the build process. Change your build script to run `signtool.exe` after the Go compiler has generated your EXE or DLL file. Provide the path and password to the private key file (if using a `.pfx` file) and it will sign it for you. This is the same process that Visual Studio uses.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/signtool

---

Apparently Go's `go build` command is surprisingly spartan: [you cannot add additional build steps nor custom commands to `go build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402956/is-it-possible-use-go-build-with-extra-build-steps), [nor is there any "hooks" feature for the `go` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374007/how-can-i-make-go-get-hooks-for-my-go-project) either (other than `go generate`, but that's a *pre-build* step when we want a *post-build* step).

...which means [you'll need a makefile](https://golangdocs.com/makefiles-golang).

- You'll need `make` as well, which you'll [need to install somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows) as it isn't a *Windows thing*:

  - Via Chocolatey: `choco install make`
  - Or [via installing WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)
  - Or you figure out [how to get these binaries from 2006 to work](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).
- *Or* you could use `nmake`, which comes with Visual Studio, [but has its own dialect for makefiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/contents-of-a-makefile?view=msvc-170), which I'm not familiar with.
- Another alternative is to consider CMake.

  - [CMake has support for `go build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978517/how-do-i-get-cmake-to-work-with-the-go-programming-language), but CMake is more of a "make-`make`" so it's outside the scope of my answer.

Here's a quick-and-dirty `makefile` (for GNU `make` on Windows) for a single-file project `main.go`, which *should* <sub>(it's untested)</sub> automatically runs `signtool` after a build:

```
# golang makefile based on https://golangdocs.com/makefiles-golang
BINARY_NAME=mygoproject.exe
 
build:
    go build -o ${BINARY_NAME} main.go

    # This runs signtool with a cert in your profile store instead of a *.pfx file, to avoid needing to store a password in the makefile or environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998439/signtool-with-certificate-stored-in-local-computer
    signtool sign /sm /s My /n <certificateSubjectName> /t http://timestamp.digicert.com ${BINARY_NAME}
 
run:
    go build -o ${BINARY_NAME} main.go
    ./${BINARY_NAME}
 
clean:
    go clean
    rm ${BINARY_NAME}
```

Just run `make build` from your terminal and it should *just work* (I hope!)